# Rundeck - any command execution fails when running on 5.8k nodes

Tags: rundeck

I'm running a rundeck server to delegate a simple script to 5.8k other linux servers.

The very simple script is bellow

## !/bin/bash

A=$(hostname)
echo $A

When i run the same job with a smaller number of targets (4089 nodes)
the comands work fine

I tried looking at my service.log page and its not incrementing anything

Any ideas on how to be able to run on all the 5.8k nodes? And where should i look for errors?

Answer (score -1):

Rundeck does not have limits to nodes, certainly depends on how many executions you want to run, how much ram, how many processors and disk space.

Maybe you need to increase the Java heap size:

https://rundeck.org/docs/administration/maintenance/tuning-rundeck.html#java-heap-size

And how to adapt this to your SSH plugin:

https://rundeck.org/docs/administration/maintenance/tuning-rundeck.html#built-in-ssh-plugins

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i don't recall seen any erors on the services.log but it'll try checking the JVM heap size

Comment: No changes on increasing the JMV heap size....I get a "Null error" but I did not found any errors on the /var/log/rundeck/* logs, even after changing the runceck log level to DEBUG... ReinerRDECK any ideias on where to go to debug it?

Comment: And about SSH Plugins? Check in documentation:

"We chose the rpm -q command which checks against the rpm database to see if a particular package was installed. For 1000 nodes we saw an average execution of 52 seconds. A 4000 node cluster took roughly 3.5 minutes, and 8000 node cluster about 7 minutes.

The main limitation appears to be memory of the JVM instance relative to the number of concurrent requests. We tuned the max memory to be 12GB with a 1000 Concurrent Dispatch Threads to 1GB of Memory. GC appears to behave well during the runs given the “bursty” nature of them."